# Why am i getting values in my first key of the dictionary only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a directory of files entitled 45-1.txt 1-17.txt etc.. basically they're 2 numbers seperated by a '-' with .txt at the end. And i have a dataset that looks like this but has thousands of lines:

```
value/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2089.0,545.0,2100.0,546.0
value/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2112.0,545.0,2136.0,554.0
value/test/45/blueprint-1.png,112.0,45.0,36.0,654.0
```

The values that I care about in these lines are the first 2 numbers of each line, so `10-0`, `10-0`,`45-1` etc.. what I want to do is to copy the lines that have the 2 numbers let's say 10-0 as a part of the name of 1 of the previous files, in this example `45-1` should be copied.

My code:

```
import os,csv,re

my_dict = {}
source_dir = '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/testing_txts/'

for element in os.listdir(source_dir):
    my_dict[element] = []
# print(my_dict)

with open('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/ground_truth.txt') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for key in my_dict:
      for filename in reader:
          print(filename)
          k = []
          k.append(re.findall(r'\d+', str(filename)))
          k1,k2 = k[0][0],k[0][1]
          k3,k4 = re.findall(r'\d+', key)
          if k3 == k1 and k2 == k4:
              my_dict[key].append(filename)

print(my_dict)
```

output example :

```
{'44-9.txt': [['value/test/44/blueprint-9.png', '1303.0', '201.0', '1348.0', '212.0'], ['value/test/44/blueprint-9.png', '1352.0', '202.0', '1399.0', '210.0']],'1-0.txt' : [], '5-6.txt' : []}
```

now the data in 44-9 is always full and adequate but 1-0 and 5-6, for example, should have values too but they don't and I can't figure out the exact issue in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reader` is an iterator, not a list/dict. This means you can go over it just once.
If you want to do multiple iterations over you reader you need to keep the values in memory. The easiest way is like this:

```
with open('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/ground_truth.txt') as f:
    reader = list(csv.reader(f))
```

And you can close the file immediately afterwards (before the loops).

Comment: Can you edit your changes into my original code, because putting `reader.close()` after it doesn't work, wanna know how you closed it so i can accept the answer.Thanks

Comment: @Jess there is no need to call reader.close() the with statement implicitly closes the file after you exit the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are using csv.reader in wrong way. Change your code to this

```
import os,csv,re

my_dict = {}
source_dir = '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/testing_txts/'

for element in os.listdir(source_dir):
    my_dict[element] = []    

input_file = open('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/ground_truth.txt')
input_file_reader = csv.reader(input_file)

for row in input_file_reader:
    for key in my_dict:
        for filename in row:
            print(filename)
            k = []
            k.append(re.findall(r'\d+', str(filename)))
            k1,k2 = k[0][0],k[0][1]
            k3,k4 = re.findall(r'\d+', key)
            if k3 == k1 and k2 == k4:
                my_dict[key].append(filename)

print(my_dict)
```